# Argument 'Set<Future<DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>>> Function(String)' can't be assigned to parameter type 'void Function(String, dynamic)'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to add multiple Firestore documents from one collection to another collection in my flutter app and so far this is the closest I've gotten to doing so.

I tried manually creating a map reading from the Firestore data and then storing it back to Firestore in another collection using `forEach()` but it fails.

I used that same function below, the `forEach()` one with a hard-coded array:

```
  var myArray69 = [
    {
      'name': 'a',
      'brand': 'bruh'
    },
    {
      'name': 'b'
    }
  ];
```

```
  myArray69.forEach((doc) => {     
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myOtherCollection69').add(doc)});
```

and it adds each array as a document to Firestore just fine, so I've been trying to replicate that using data from another collection without luck.

Here's my code:

```
Widget _foodList(){
  return Expanded(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('foodShelf')
          .snapshots(),
        builder: buildFoodList,
      ),
  );
}


Widget buildFoodList(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

    DocumentSnapshot food = snapshot.data.docs[index];
    
    var foodName = food.get('foodName');

    var someMap = {
      "a": foodName,
      "b": '2',
      };

    return GestureDetector(
      key: Key(food.id),
      onTap: () {
        someMap.forEach((doc) => {      // <-----  First error is here
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myOtherCollection69').add(doc)});
        print(someMap);
      },
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(foodName),
      ),
    );
  } 
);
}
```

If I comment out this section:

```
  someMap.forEach((doc) => {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myOtherCollection69').add(doc)});
```

Leave only the `print(someMap);` and I tap on one of the results on screen, I get the map in the console:

[image]

```
I/flutter ( 6922): {a: Pure 100% florida orange juice, b: 2}
```

But I'm not able to add it to Firestore using this code, I get the following errors:

- First error:

```
The argument type 'Set<Future<DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>>> Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String, dynamic)'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
```

- Second error:

```
The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `myArray69` is a `List` of a `Map<String, String>`,
there a `forEach` loop would give a result in a `Map` which is accepted by the `add(doc)` method.
The `Map` list gives a `Map` itemlike this:
`myArray69.forEach(void Function(Map<String, String>) function)`.

But,
your `someMap` variable is a `Map` itself.
So if you were to use `forEach` on that, it would give you 2 values.
One as a `key` & the other as a `value` assigned to the key.
The `forEach` operation would give:
`someMap.forEach((key, value) => print([key, value]));`

So to answer your question, you should directly add the `Map` instead of looping it.
Example:

```dart
onTap: () {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myOtherCollection69').add(someMap);
  print(someMap);;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazing, after struggling for hours with this, I post the question and immediately figure out how to solve my problem.

Made this change to my custom map and that made it work (add a document to firestore):

```
(-) var someMap = {
     "a": foodName,
     "b": '2',
    };
```

```
(+) List<Map<String, String>> someMap = [
      {
        "a": foodName,
        "b": '2',
      }
    ];
```

Now I'm still struggling to add ALL the documents from one collection to another at once.